# .htaccess rewrite issue only loading homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permissions

I have moved a site from my test dev to a live server (its wordpress) and for some reason no matter what page I click on only the homepage loads.

Think I have narrowed it down to my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and this line in particular:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If I remove this or remove the htaccess completly I get a Forbidden 403 error.

I was hoping someone could help me figure this out?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there were a bunch of random files in the root, with the FTP I only had access to the public_html. There were a number of htaccess files and other config files which we cleared out and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Very common issue is redirect plugin. Disable all plugins and post back. Have you got your website in the root folder or is it in the sub directory?

Update:

## Changing the Site URL

> There are four easy methods to change the Site URL manually. Any of these methods will work and perform much the same function.
>   Edit wp-config.php
>
> It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.
>
> Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.
>
> define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
>   define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

This is not necessarily the best fix, it's just hardcoding the values into the site itself. You won't be able to edit them on the General settings page anymore when using this method.

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Update:

Goto
    wp-config.php

and add

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: its in the root, and I have disabled my plugins folder by re-naming it with no luck, I cant even access my wp-admin as it just loads the homepage. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the urls are correct, I tried uploading the core WP files again with no luck.

Comment: Try and login using this  yoursite.com/wp-login.php

Comment: no matter what URL you try it just loads the homepage...bizarre it must be a server config issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17956/discussion-between-david-murray-and-matt)

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions but its not the standard path WP issue. I am now confident its a server issue as I tried a fresh WP install via a 1 click install (softaculous) and even that one is having the same issue. Ill update when I resolve the issue.